# split strings and assign them to dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, split

I have a text file containing many lines which look like this:

> Flowers{Tulip|Sun Flower|Rose}
>
> Gender{Female|Male}
>
> Pets{Cat|Dog|Rabbit}

I know how to read lines from a file, but what's the best way to split and store the categories and their subitems in a dictionary afterwards? Let's say from a string array which contains all the above lines?

Comment: what do you want from output? one *key* and some *value*?

Comment: I want to add the categories (e.g. Flowers) as items in a listView and when I select the category I want to display the subcategories (Tulipa, Sun Flower, Rose) in a second listView. But to know how to split it right and put it into a dictionary would be very helpful.

Comment: Are the "|" placeholders for possible values or is it an actual character within your file?

Comment: Yes they are actual characters. I use them as separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea to use a regexp is right, but I prefer using named captures for readability

```
var regexp = new Regex(@"(?<category>\w+?)\{(?<entities>.*?)\}");
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

// you would replace this list with the lines read from the file
var list = new string[] {"Flowers{Tulip|Sun Flower|Rose}"
                         , " Gender{Female|Male}"
                         , "Pets{Cat|Dog|Rabbit}"};

foreach (var entry in list)
{
    var mc = regexp.Matches(entry);
    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        d.Add(m.Groups["category"].Value
            , m.Groups["entities"].Value.Split('|').ToList());
    }
}
```

You get a dictionary with the category as a key, and the values in a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `Key` and `value` on this code

```
string T = @"Flowers{Tulip|Sun Flower|Rose}

Gender{Female|Male}

Pets{Cat|Dog|Rabbit}";

foreach (var line in T.Split('\n'))//or while(!file.EndOfFile)
{
    var S = line.Split(new char[] { '{', '|','}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string Key = S[0];
    MessageBox.Show(Key);//sth like this
    for (int i = 1 ; i < S.Length; i++)
    {
        string value = S[i];
        MessageBox.Show(value);//sth like this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\w+){(\w+)}");
```

now loop the results of this regex:

```
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(line)) {
    yourDict.Add(m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2].Split(' '));
}
```